# How can I replace the first and last char of a string in C#?

Tags: c#

I have a simple question, and I did some research but couldn't find the right answer for it.

I have this string:

> |She wants to eat breakfast|

I found the answer for replacing ALL the characters `|` with another character.

My idea is that I want to replace the first `|` with `{` and the last one with `}`.

I know this is easy, but I the answer for this question would really help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`string.Substring`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs.aspx):

```
s = "{" + s.Substring(1, s.Length - 2) + "}";
```

See it working online: [ideone](http://ideone.com/TtqCr)

This assumes that the characters you want to replace are the very first and last characters in the string.

Comment: But is this really what OP wants: _"I want to replace the first "|" with "{" and the last one with "}"."_

Comment: @TimSchmelter: My answer is not incompatible with that quote. It depends on what assumptions you make. I'm assuming that the string starts and ends with `|`. I think that's a valid assumption given the combination of a) the OPs example b) the question's title "How can I replace the first and last char of a string in C#?" and c) he says it works. But obviously only the OP knows what assumptions must be made.

Answer (score 2):

If you use .Net 3 and higher and you don't want to use an extension method then you can prefer Lambda for a little bit better performance than normal string operations..

```
string s = "|she wants to eat breakfast|";
s.Replace(s.ToCharArray().First(ch => ch == '|'), '{'); //this replaces the first '|' char
s.Replace(s.ToCharArray().Last(ch => ch == '|'), '}'); // this replaces the last '|' char
```

Comment: This doesn't work - `s.Replace` doesn't change the instance s and the first replace would act on both instances of char '|'

Answer (score 1):

```
string oldString = "|She wants to eat breakfast|";
string newString = "{" + oldString.SubString(1,oldString.Length-2) + "}";
```

or using string.Concat (the internal implementation of + operator for strings calls string.Concat)

```
string newString = string.Concat("{",oldString.SubString(1,oldString.Length-2),"}");
```

Answer (score 0):

The **fastest** way to go would be this:

```
var str = "|She wants to eat breakfast|";

unsafe
{
    fixed (char* pt = str)
    {
        pt[0] = '{';
        pt[str.Length - 1] = '}';
    }
}

Console.WriteLine(str); // Prints: {She wants to eat breakfast}
```

You will need to enable **unsafe code** (Right-click project > properties > build > "Allow unsafe code".

This is about **19 times faster** than using Substring and adding bracelets at the edges.

Comment: I am just curious, what about using ToCharArray and String.Join? Is it faster than Substring?

Comment: @Sam It will probably end up the same, if not slower. Using the unsafe code, however, is surely the fastest way to do it.

Comment: @Sam I tested it and it is actually a LOT slower. Unsafe > Substring > TCA+Join.

Comment: @Sam How would reversing the string do us any good in this case?

Comment: Sorry, I corrected it:


            var array = str.ToCharArray();
            array[0] = '{';
            array[array.Length-1] = '}';
            var reversed = new String(array);

Comment: That goes in between unsafe and Substring. I can't imagine how anything would be faster than unsafe (considering it has to be C#), because you are using an already used memory, and you have no reallocations whatsoever.